# not found mingw32[64] installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

Initially, I did `git clone https://github.com/r00t-3xp10it/FakeImageExploiter.git`
sadf
afdasfadsf
and when I extract ./FakeImageExploiter.sh
then

```
[☆] Checking backend applications.
[x] mingw32[64] installation -> not found!
[x] This script requires mingw32[64] to work
[☆] Please wait: installing missing dependencies.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mingw32

[☆] Wine installation: found!
[☆] Xterm installation: found!
[☆] Zenity installation: found!
[☆] Wine Program Files: found!
[☆] FakeImageExploiter needs to restart to finish installs ..
```

occur
but I did

```
root@ubuntu:/home/lay/FakeImageExploiter# sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mingw-w64 is already the newest version (5.0.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install mingw-w32` then `E: Unable to locate package mingw-w32`

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I am suffering with the same thing. I tried the steps described here:.
https://github.com/r00t-3xp10it/FakeImageExploiter/issues/22

You can download and install mingw32 manually and them FakeImageExploiter runs. But it does not work fine:.

```
Building : evil agent ..
sed: can't read evil.c: No such file or directory
[☆] Compiling: agent using mingw32 ..
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.3-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
./build/i686-w64-mingw32-i686-w64-mingw32-crt/./mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[☆] ResourceHacker.exe: found ..
[☆] Working: In backdoor agent ..
[☆] Change : backdoor agent icons ..
[☆] Change : backdoor agent extension ..
[☆] Port: all files to apache2 webserver ..
[☆] Creating: archive teste.zip ..
[☆] Creating: resource cleaner.rc ..
sed: can't read cleaner.rc: No such file or directory
[☠] Metamorphosis: completed ..

    ATTACK VECTOR: http://172.16.10.30/teste.zip
    AGENT: /root/output/teste..exe
    CLEAN: meterpreter > resource /root/output/cleaner.rc
```

No payload is generated in the output and I am stuck on here. But try installing manually mingw32 I hope it works for you